# How to put blocks in line in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following code, where I wanted to align logo(picture) and one block, which includes Username, his level and progress bar. And used flex for it, but it ate my progress bar, how can I do it so error bar's width would be 100%?

```
<div class="class" id="user"> 
            <img src="user.svg"> 
            <div>
                <h2>username</h2> 
                <h2> Уровень </h2>
               <div id="container">
                    <div id="progress"> 80% </div>
               </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: User]

The CSS of the page:

```
#user { 
    display:flex; 
} 

#container {
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
#progress{
    background-color: #fd6a72;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your elements some width.

```css
#user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

#progress {
  background-color: #fd6a72;
  width: calc(100vw - 25px - 8px);
  height: 20px;
}

img{
height:25px;}
```

```html
<div class="class" id="user"> 
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25"> 
            <div>
                <h2>username</h2> 
                <h2> Уровень </h2>
               <div id="container">
                    <div id="progress"> 80% </div>
               </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```